# How to use part of a 2D array in a ForEach loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, 2d, each

`array` is a 2D array, these are the elements:

- [0] [2]  [4] [6] [8]
- [12] [14] [6] [6] [10]

How can I use a `for`-each loop to access only the second line of `array`?

I've tried doing...

```
for (int n : array[1])
     n++;
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: which language is this?

Comment: I have never seen a 2D array that looks like that

Comment: This is in Java, I am just showing what the elements in the array are/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, the arrays are zero-based so your idea of [1] to point to the second dimension is headed in the right direction. Try this: increment over the size of the array's first dimension, and access the second inside the loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        System.out.println(array[i][1]);
```

You originally asked about a for-each approach. In Java multi-dimensional arrays are just an array of arrays, so you want to get each sub-array in turn and print the second element of it. Like this:

```
    for (int sub[] : array)
       System.out.println(sub[1]);
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I ended up doing. Do you know if there is a way to use a for-each loop? Or does it just have to be like that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is with your **2D array** creation. For-each loop you are using is correct. Make sure you create the array as follows:

```
int[][] arr = {{0, 2, 4, 6, 8},{12, 14, 6, 6, 10}};
```

If you use **System.out.println** in your loop, it will print **12, 14, 6, 6, 10**.